# My child theme doesn't work Error: "The parent theme is missing. Please install your parent theme"

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme, parent-theme

I am using the Pricerr theme. In my parent theme I have a CSS folder with a few css files in it, a `rtl.css` and a `style.css`.

What should be the code to put in the functions folder so that I can pull the info from the parents theme? And am i on the right track for identifying this as the error when they say "The parent theme is missing. Please install your parent theme?"

I've checked and my parent theme is under `Appearance > Themes` hence it is definitely loaded.

Comment: Pricerr is a commercial theme, ask the theme's support for help.

Comment: What does your child theme style.css have for `Template:`? Your parent theme should be fully installed (it does not sound like it unless you meant that is what is in your child theme directory?) and this field should point to the parent theme slug.

Comment: I think this might be what went wrong. This is what is in my child theme's function.php:

<?php
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $pricerrtheme = 'pricerrtheme';

    wp_enqueue_style( $pricerrtheme, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'pricerrtheme-child',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $pricerrtheme )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>

It looks wrong... :/

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code. It's not readable in this way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are three things to check:

1. Is your parent theme complete and what is the exact spelling of the parent theme's name in its `style.css`. Uppercase and lowercase are important.
2. Is the child theme directory named `parentname-child`. It should be in the themes directory, not in a subdirectory of the parent theme.
3. Does the child theme's `style.css` have the line `Template: parentname` in its header. Beware: NOT `Template: parentname-child`.

Strictly speaking you don't need a `functions.php` file for your child theme, but you will probably want to load the parent theme's `style.css` as well. Read more about that [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: This is in my child theme's style.css:
/*
Theme Name: PricerrTheme Child
Theme URI: http://sitemile.com/products/wordpress-pricerr-theme/
Description: Child theme for the PricerrTheme theme
Author: SiteMile
Author URI: http://sitemile.com/products/wordpress-pricerr-theme/
Template: pricerrtheme
Version: 3.1.3
Tags: job, blue, bid, budget, rating, feedback
*/

Comment: And this is in my parent theme's style.css:
/*
Theme Name: PricerrTheme
Theme URI: http://sitemile.com/products/wordpress-pricerr-theme/
Description: The only wordpress theme that will let you run a job/auction fixed price site.
Author: SiteMile
Author URI: http://sitemile.com/products/wordpress-pricerr-theme/
Version: 3.1.3
Tags: job, blue, bid, budget, rating, feedback
*/

Is it correct? :/

Comment: You need `Template: PricerrTheme` in the child css. It's all lowercase now.

Comment: It worked!! I've been trying to figure it out for the longest time. Thanks a bunch!! :D Is it true i don't need the function.php file in child theme?

Comment: Strictly speaking `functions.php` is not necessary, but it depends on how the parent theme loads styles. So if it works: don't touch it anymore. ;-) Also: don't forget to accept the answer, so it wil not pop up as "unsolved" later.

Comment: Yes it loads fine so i'm not going to touch the functions anymore. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks a lot - this just saved me!

Answer (score 11):

The Template Name in the Child Theme Should be Parent theme's Folder name., If you give the Parent theme Name or something else It won't work.

Is your theme "pricerr" provided by 'sitemile' ?

then the template name should be like

Template: PricerrTheme

Comment: Also, be sure to check the capitalization of the Template name. It should match the folder's capitalization, which is likely lowercase.

Comment: @Pikamander2 you should made that an answer - even paid theme authors get this wrong... one would expect at least for money it would be set-up well x)

Answer (score 2):

This question has long been answered, but since I stumbled here and this did not solve my problem, I thought I would add another solution.

In my case, the template was set correctly in both the parent and the child theme, but the *parent theme's folder* was not named what it expected. Despite all of the files themselves being correct, this can be a parent folder name issue.

Comment: The template for the child theme wasn't correct then, was it?

Comment: @JacobPeattie The child theme was correct. I erred when I unzipped the parent theme (used incorrect name for folder).

Comment: @JacobPeattie this seems to be a common bug by theme authors: they distribute themes from a case-insensitive operating system, which breaks WordPress for everyone who installs the theme - but you only notice when making a child-theme. Wordpress's error messages for this are incorrect (they know for certain that they have a theme with wrong folder name, but instead they report an error in child-theme).